# Has anyone encountered a universal Object to String formatter for Java?

Tags: java

Has anyone encountered a universal Object to String formatter for Java?  I'm imagining something that would use reflection to discovery properties of an arbitrary object (probably just a JavaBean, but probably including some properties which are `Collection`s or `Maps`s) and format the object as a `String`?  This is in a situation where I do not have any control over the `toString()` implementations of the target classes.

Does something like this exist somewhere?

Comment: Universal? I think not. What's a serialised Socket going to look like for example.

Comment: {
  "created": false,
  "bound": false,
  "connected": false,
  "closed": false,
  "closeLock": {},
  "shutIn": false,
  "shutOut": false,
  "impl": {
    "@class": "java.net.SocksSocketImpl",
    "socket": {
      "@reference": "../.."
    },
    "port": {
      "@defined-in": "java.net.SocketImpl",
      "$": "0"
    },
    "localport": 0,
    "timeout": 0,
    "trafficClass": 0,
    "shut_rd": false,
    "shut_wr": false,
    "fdUseCount": 0,
    "fdLock": {},
    "closePending": false,
    "CONNECTION_NOT_RESET": 0,
    "CONNECTION_RESET_PENDING": 1,
    "CONNECTION_RESET": 2,
etc etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object serializers usually do exactly that. For example [JSON](http://www.json.org/java/) serializes to text (JS more precisely) but there are others as well.

Comment: Went with XStream, where it's ridiculously easy to do this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try [here](http://tinyurl.com/3ylnwsu).

Reflection is not the best choice regarding performance, though. Also, some classes' private members might be quite uninteresting and spam your output if they are included in the toString() return value.

Comment: Reflection has performance issues, but it is probably the *only* way to implement a truly **universal** formatter.